# Fool-Proof Group Chat in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, jquery

I am trying to implement group chat (only group chat) functionality using Ajax, PHP, MySql.

What I have tried till now:

1- Ajax short polling with caching to reduce number of database hits. But it is rejected by number of developer's because Number http request's.
2- Ajax long polling, which is quite good idea but it is not working with IE even if I made every ajax request unique.

So please give me some solution so that I will be able to implement group chat functionality in my project. I am open to new suggestions to implement group chat.

Comment: How about APE for scalable push? http://www.ape-project.org/

Comment: Have you tried http://socket.io/? or, even easier http://www.rumbletalk.com?

Comment: Yeah I have gone through that but Do you recommend APE for group chat feature only.

Answer (score 1):

A group chat on short polling would be extremely inefficient. It's not true real-time (a few seconds of delay unless you want to hit the db every single instance then your gonna hurt the system)

Now with ajax (short polling or long polling) it could a solution but not an effective choice especially when talking about scalability!

A newish technology node.js would be the perfect solution. If you don't know what node is, it's fairly simple. Think a non-blocking io javascript on the server. Now this would require a learning curve if you are not already familiar with javascript but i assume you are. Second is that this is a php question combined with cakephp which node.js replaces completely.

Now node.js provides many many frameworks that are similar to Sinatra, Rails, and some other php alternatives. From a simple Sinatra based framework to a full stacked mvc framework node has it all.

I recently been extremely interested in [Express](http://expressjs.com/), which is a sinatra type framework. It provides it's own view templating system "Jade" but you can use any other engine you wish. The site gives a few [screencasts](http://expressjs.com/screencasts.html) showing a few example applications and some tutorials showing the power of node.js and Express. You can write detailed and advanced applications in an extremely short time span since both the front-end and back-end is written in one language (javascript). It also provides a nice html alternative mark-up.

Though Express is only one of many frameworks, i'm sure there is one you would be interested in. You can find a stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809539/choosing-a-web-application-framework-using-node-js).

I did find a chat application written in node.js available on [github](https://github.com/endtwist/AjaxIM) though it's not in active development any more, it's still a good resource to look at and see how other people have implemented their chat systems.

Another aspect of node is the database tool. You can actively make queries in node utilizing the none-blocking io architecture.

There are plenty of ways but the more efficient is the question. A note to be made is that you need a server that supports node.js, some new cloud services are specializing in node. A simple google search might find some good ones.

Hope this helps,
Daniel

EDIT: I also forgot to mention that to get a fully real-time chat you can use socket.io. Though the real reason to use node is because it's meant to be used in an event driven non-blocking io way. It also has an extremely small footprint, so scaling is not an issue.

Comment: First of all thanks for your support, Did they all related to comet somehow.

Comment: what do you think about mootools?

Comment: I don't have much experience with mootools. I used it back in the day for a little while then I went with jQuery. Though I guess it's up to your own personal preference, i prefer jquery. If you have any issues while working with jquery you tend to always find your answer online since the community is fairly large. Just my two cents.